# What is the difference between an `eml` file and an RFC822 email message?

Tags: email, mime, file-format, rfc822

I see these two terms used interchangeably in a lot of context, but some sources say that `eml` is a file format that originated with Microsoft Outlook.

Is `eml` the official file suffix of an RFC822 message saved as a flat text file?

Comment: as far as I know, .eml files are always rfc822 text. I don't know a "official" document to back that up, so I'm only posting that as a comment. I'd say, the answer to your question is "yes"

Answer (score 2):

There is no official definition of what "eml" means, and different programs use it in different ways.  Sometimes people use it to mean RFC822, other times they mean something different.  If you mean RFC822 format, say so.